# How to establish a connection My Mobile device with my PC to execute a performance test using Jmeter.?

Tags: jmeter, jmx, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

I am using an android device version 4.3.I have to connect My Mobile with Jmeter console to execute a performance test.I have to know the the Proxy Host Name to Provide in the WIFI config area.Currently when I try to launch a browser with in the device ,it shows error like "Unable to connect to the proxy server".Also I need to know any more configurations to be done to execute or record the actions.?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you are trying to to

I have found that launching a command line test via Jenkins to be a great means of executing JMeter tests, and because of the Jenkins web interface I can launch tests directly from my mobile device.

Comment: I just want to congigure the WIFI in the mobile device.For that I need to know about the proxy address of my laptop.So my question is how to get this proxy address of my laptop which is to be set in my mobile.

Comment: That does not really have anything to do with Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late, but we wrote an article on Mobile Load Testing, that just might answer your question:

http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy

I hope it does.